# Automapper cant fill Child Objects (v.6.1.1)

Tags: automapper

I have this main class with 2 complex nested objects

```
public class OrderData
{
    public OrderDO OrderDO { get; set; }
    public CustomerDO CustomerDO { get; set; 

}
```

My OrderDO Class

```
public class OrderDO
    {
        public OrderDO()
        {
            OrderItemDOList = new List<OrderItemDO>();
            PaymentLogDOList = new List<PaymentLogDO>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...
        }
    }
```

And CustomerDO Class

```
public class CustomerDO
    {
        public CustomerDO()
        {
            OrderDOList = new List<OrderDO>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Last OrderItemDO Class

```
public class OrderItemDO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I cant make mapping OrderItemDOList and PaymentLogDOList under OrderDO :

```
OrderDO orderDO = Mapper.Map<OrderMain, OrderDO>(orderMain);
```

OrderItemDOList and PaymentLogDOList are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I find this way. Child Mapping types will be declared with
>
> ```
> ForMember()
> ```
>
> method

Like This :

```
config.CreateMap<OrderMain, OrderDO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderItemDOList, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.OrderItem))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PaymentLogDOList, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.PaymentLog));

config.CreateMap<OrderDO, OrderMain>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderItem, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.OrderItemDOList))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PaymentLog, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.PaymentLogDOList));

config.CreateMap<OrderItemDO, OrderItem>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DisplayName, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.DisplayName));

config.CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemDO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DisplayName, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.DisplayName));

config.CreateMap<PaymentLog, PaymentLogDO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderId, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(fa => fa.OrderId));
```

Answer (score 1):

As mapping between complex objects is a simple thing which AutoMapper definitely does well, this leaves the likely cause of the problem as one of the following:

- The source objects are not populated (lazy loading?)
- You have not defined mappings between the inner objects

You can check the first item with a breakpoint on your call to Mapper.Map.

While you've not included enough code to determine if it's the second issue, you can most likely find this yourself by *testing your mappings*: simply run `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`.  If AutoMapper doesn't know how to map something you've got, it'll tell you what the problem is in the exception.

Comment: I mapping same classes but difference is name. Such as OrderItem and OrderItemDO.Inner objects are not mapping. I define map rules.